# Limit and an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-numbers

Let, $0\leq r<1$ and $$I(r)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\log\left|\frac{1}{1-re^{ix}}\right|}{|1-re^{ix}|} dx\tag{1}$$
What will be $\lim_{r\to 1^-}I(r)$?

My attempt: Define $s=\frac{1}{1-re^{ix}}$ then $$ 1-re^{ix}=\frac{1}{s}$$ and so we have $$re^{ix}=\frac{s-1}{s} $$
So we get taking modulus of above equation $$ r=\left|\frac{s-1}{s}\right|\tag{2}$$
Write $s=x+iy$ in $(2)$, so we get $$r^2=1+\frac{1-2x}{x^2+y^2}$$

So as $r\to 1^-$ in $(2)$ and since $1-2x<0$, we have $|s|=x^2+y^2\to \infty$

So in equation $(1)$ as $r\to 1^-$, $$\log\left|\frac{1}{1-re^{ix}}\right|\geq 0 $$
Now taking modulus in both sides in $(1)$ and the fact that $|1-re^{ix}|\geq 1-r$,
$$|I(r)|\leq \frac{1}{1-r} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log\left|\frac{1}{1-re^{ix}}\right| dx$$
Your insights is needed.

Comment: We may have $|1-re^{\mathrm{i}x}|^{-1} > 1$ for e.g. for $x = \pi/2$ and thus $\log|1-re^{\mathrm{i}x}|^{-1} \geq 0$ is not true for all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. So you argument is not correct. It is possible to show that the integrand is even inegrable for $r=1$, but it is a lot of work and I am not sure if the exact value can be calculated.

Comment: I have done one mistake in my calculations. So, the function seems to be not intrgrable for $r=1$. If my numerical calculations are not wrong, we shall expect $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} I(r) = - \infty$.

Comment: If we take $z = e^{i x}$ and use the fact that $|1 - r z| = \sqrt {1 - r z} \sqrt {1 - r/z}$ on the unit circle, we get an integral of an analytic function. Then we can deform the contour of integration to $[-i0, r - i0] \cup [r + i0, i0]$ to obtain
$$I(r) = \int_0^1 \frac
 {-2 \ln(1 - r^2 u)} {\sqrt {u - u^2} \sqrt {1 - r^2 u}} du$$
(incidentally, this gives a simple derivation of the ascending Landen transformation for $K$). Since the integrand is non-negative and non-decreasing as a function of $r$, we can interchange the limit and the integral.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $$\lim_{r \to 1^-} I(r) = + \infty$$

Checking numerically for $r=1-2^{-k}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & I\left[1-2^{-k}\right]\\
 1 & 0.9699203 \\
 2 & 3.1595486 \\
 3 & 6.3415571 \\
 4 & 10.506974 \\
 5 & 15.663449 \\
 6 & 21.812764 \\
 7 & 28.951203 \\
 8 & 37.072737 \\
 9 & 46.171300 \\
 10 & 56.242017
\end{array}
\right)$$

A quick and dirty nonlinear regression
$$I\left[1-2^{-k}\right]=a+b \,k^n$$ gives, with $R^2=0.9999935$,

$$\begin{array}{llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std. Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.354949 & 0.081062 & \{0.156599,0.553300\} \\
 b & 0.755546 & 0.015072 & \{0.718665,0.792427\} \\
 c & 1.868466 & 0.008473 & \{1.847734,1.889198\} \\
\end{array}$$